# Use fraction entity on reputation page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, help-center

On the [What is reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) help page, you fan find the following:

> one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount

I think it would look nicer with the fraction entity `&frac12;`:

> one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +½ of the bounty amount

Minor? Yes. Would it look better? Yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, why not. <strike>Enjoy the prettier fraction.</strike>

Based on the other answer here, I changed the fraction to a word.

Comment: Hey Laura, what's your take on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243239/152859)?

Comment: While we're fixing minor things, can we add the appropriate space in "6 spam or offensive flags:−100" (between "flags:" and "−100")?

Comment: @animuson done.

Answer (score 6):

I consider *+ half bounty amount* or *+ half the bounty amount* better as it is in line with *+full bounty amount* a few lines further up. Also, it does not irritate users skimming the list and only reading the ½.

(While somebody is at it, a thin space after + or − if they are followed by text and not a number would be nice.)

Comment: I agree. I think the number looks stupid there, especially as a random fraction character that matches **nothing** else on the site.

Comment: I don't think it much matters, but sure, have a word instead of a fraction.